# How Can I use Google OR Microsoft Push Notification for 2 factor authentication in my JAVA based web app

Tags: java, authentication, google-authentication

I want to enable two factor authentication (**with Push Notification**) in my JAVA based web application.

I searched and found I can use Google & Microsoft authenticator app and can enable two factor authentication, I have successfully done POC for this and it works well with random code generated in Authenticator app and on my web app server and can verify the code. https://medium.com/@ihorsokolyk/two-factor-authentication-with-java-and-google-authenticator-9d7ea15ffee6

Now I want to enable Push notification in a same way, whenever user login to my webApp,after user name & password verification, I want to send push notification to user's registered mobile number OR in user's Google/Microsoft authenticator app, with YES, NO options. user will then select YES or NO and based on that response, user should be able to login in my web app.

I searched but not find any such API of Google or Microsoft which I can use in my web App to support push notification. Appreciate your help if any one can provide links to such API docs or  have any other suggestion to achieve this requirement.

Thanks